# Can a master sell his slave after having intercourse with her?

Tags: slavery

As far as I understand, when a concubine gives birth to her master's child, her status would be "mother of the child" (umm al-walad) and she can't be sold anymore.

My question: **Can a master sell his slave after having intercourse with her and she doesn't become pregnant?**

If yes, what prevents the abuse of having intercourse with a slave and afterwards selling her off to other people and buying new female slaves to have intercourse with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes he can do that, as long as the concubine does not become pregnant and as long as the waiting period is observed to ensure that she has not become pregnant.

There is no law to prevent this, just as there is nothing to prevent a person from continually divorcing and marrying other free women.

**Ref:** https://sunnah.com/muslim:1438a and its [commentary](https://shamela.ws/book/1711/2125) etc.

Comment: Thanks! Since you referenced the hadith: as far as I understand you can only have intercourse with a (new) slave after she observed at least one menstrual cycle. Do we assume that the companions in the referenced hadith did that?

Comment: yes⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀