# why are concubines sold after being consummated with?

Tags: hadith, slavery, nikah-al-mutah

Abu Sa’id said We went out with the Apostle of Allaah(ﷺ) on the expedition to Banu Al Mustaliq and took some Arab women captive and we desired the women for we were suffering from the absence of our wives and we wanted ransom, so we intended to withdraw the penis (while having intercourse with the slave women).
-Sunan Abi Dawud 2172

Abu¯ Salama b. Abd al-Rah˙
ma¯n informed me from Abu¯ Sa ı¯d al-Khudrı¯, who said:
As I set out to sell a slave girl of mine in the market, one of the Jews said, “O Abu¯ Sa ı¯d,
perhaps you desire to sell her because an infant from you is in her womb!” I said, “No,
indeed I had safe sex with her.”
-kitab al maghazi al waqidi

“They [men] take as a favorite a female
slave who has passed through the hands of innumerable male owners ...
They [men] do not show sexual jealousy when it comes to female slaves
who are the mothers of [their] children and the favorites of kings; yet they
display sexual jealousy when it comes to free women.”
-Al-Jahiz, Risala al-qiyan,

The above quotes suggest that men can just consummate with slave girls and sell them away afterwards. What is the rationale behind this I thought it is virtuous for Muslims to be in long term fulfilling relationships rather than temporary pleasure relationships like mut'ah. What if the woman happened to be sold pregnant what would happen to the child and also what about STD's from repetitively being sold?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a master sell his slave after having intercourse with her?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/77068/can-a-master-sell-his-slave-after-having-intercourse-with-her)

Comment: @UmH sort of but I added additional questions

Answer (score -4):

Few points to note;

1. The concubines cannot be forced to engage in intercourse first and foremost, so it would always be a mutual agreement.
2. Having a slave woman live with you as a man can naturally lead to sexual desires towards the woman. The woman has a right to satisfy her desire too and Allah has provided a way for both the man and slave woman to mutually satisfy each other.
3. Allah encourages marrying the slave woman rather than treating them as a concubine, even though it's permissible.
4. The slave woman could satisfy the man when his wife is on her menses, reducing the chance of zina and immoral thoughts.
5. The slave woman can become pregnant and marry the owner becoming a free woman.

Overall, Allah has shown us just some of the wisdom by allowing it, whilst as the same time encouraging marriage overall, even to the slaves. Every man knows their own inner desire, and some are stronger than others, so this is just one way to satisfy them whilst providing a mutual benefit to both man and woman.

Comment: Thanks for your response but It adressed none of the citations I mentioned nor answered any of the questions