# Questions about female muslim slaves

Tags: fiqh, sharia

So, this is my last question regarding this topic.

If a concubine accepts Islam, my understanding is that she is still enslaved and can be bought and sold. If a muslim man sells her off after using her for intercourse, and her new owner also uses her for intercourse, isn't this not dishonouring our muslim womenfolk? Can the slave owner sell her to a kaafir, this would be considered adultery?

Is there anything limiting simply buying and reselling concubines? Their chastity seems to be violated with how much men could potentially sleep with them.

My apologies for the harshness.

Comment: You need to ask one focused question per post. For the permissibility of selling after intercourse see [Can a master sell his slave after having intercourse with her?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/77068/).

Comment: If the slave is a Muslim then he or she can not be sold to a kafir.